# How to turn row values into columns?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to have `unique values` of one `column` as `rows` and the other `columns` `unique values` as `columns`. I'm not sure if this is the right explanation so I'll just leave a screenshot of what I want to happen. Sorry it was made in a rush.

Example:

[image: example]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 0):

You need to basically join the table to itself.

You can perform a query like this:

**The Query**

```
SELECT chat.chat_id, chat.chat_user AS chat_user1, chat2.chat_user AS chat_user2
FROM chat as chat, chat as chat2
WHERE chat.chat_id = chat2.chat_id
AND chat.chat_user != chat2.chat_user
GROUP BY chat_id
```

Which will join it to itself and check for all groups of chat_id and return the result with an extra column as you want.

**SELECT AS**

Importantly to change column names you can SELECT column1 AS new_column1, column2 AS new_column2

This is particularly useful if you have ambiguous column names which of course you will when joining a table to itself in essence.

**WHERE / AND**

Here we are first checking the chat_id is the same so all chat_ids that equal 14 for example get returned, however to stop it creating multiple rows we tell it to ignore chat_users that have already been put into chat_user2 on the first run through of the code.

**GROUP BY**

This stops it creating duplicate rows of data and returns one result for each chat_id

I've assumed you're table is called chat for this. If not replace chat with your table name